# Select all entries where range of two DATETIME fields includes given date

Tags: mysql

I'm looking for a way to get all entries from my reservations table to be shown in a calendar.

Now I know that I will have to iterate over all days of the current week  and run a database query to select all reservations with `dt_from >= start_of_the_week / start_of_the_day` and `dt_to <= end_of_the_week / end_of_the_day`.

But that only gives me the reservations that start or end within the week / respectively within the given day.

What I am trying to figure out is:
How do I get the reservations which started earlier and/or end after the current day or week?

I have some kind of the following table design

`+----+-------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| ID |       NAME        |       DT_FROM       |        DT_TO        |
+----+-------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|  1 | Jeff Atwood       | 2020-01-06 09:00:00 | 2020-01-16 09:00:00 |
|  2 | Terry Jones       | 2020-01-30 09:00:00 | 2020-02-16 09:00:00 |
|  3 | Brian of Nazareth | 2020-02-06 09:00:00 | 2020-03-16 09:00:00 |
+----+-------------------+---------------------+---------------------+`

I have been stuck with this for a while now and would appreciate a push into the right direction.

Thank you :)

Comment: If you need to check that two intervals overlaps you must check that each interval start is less then the end of another interval. I.e. `(dt_from <= end_of_the_week / end_of_the_day) AND (dt_to >= start_of_the_week / start_of_the_day)`.

Comment: You had given the table data sample. Please add your code to your question.